# Highlight part of a string in data.table output R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

Let's say I have the following output of text. Using Quanteda `kwic()` , I want to find verbatims that match a pattern. I want to be able to show the output as a single line and not 3 columns so I reshape to and merge them together. I want to be able highlight the pattern word in the string. Is this at all do-able? and If so, how?

```
  # Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),



    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Histogram ----
      fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput("table1"))

    )
  )



server= function(input,output){

  output$table1 = renderDataTable({
    y = kwic(x = data_corpus_inaugural,pattern = 'united',window = 10,valuetype = 'regex')
    y = as.data.table(y)
    y = y[,4:6]
    y$new = do.call('paste',y)
    y = y[,!c(1:3)]


  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: your `ui` is not working

Comment: whoopsie. Better now.

Comment: this might help: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/006-highlight.html

Comment: that works! Just have to default the search to the input selected by the user. Thanks again!

Comment: You may want to add your own answer. It will be easier for the users who come across your post.

Answer (score 2):

Shout out to @MLavoie for the link in the comments.

To highlight selected text, repalce the 'da' with the input provided by the user.

```
   datatable(mtcars2, options = list(searchHighlight = TRUE, search = list(search = 'da')))
```